# Bottom navigation view icon color is not accurate

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

As the title suggested, the color of the bottom navigation icon is not accurate, I thought it was my eye playing trick on me so I set the background to the exact same color code, took a screenshot, check for color in photoshop:

[Here is the picture to the color test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyBi2.png)

Below is the color code for background and the icon:

```
<color name="colorNavigationIconSelected">#FFEB3B</color>
<color name="colorBackground">#FFEB3B</color>
```

And code for layout that contains bottom navigation view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0sp"
    android:background="@color/colorNavigationBar"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
<include layout="@layout/loading_layout"/> 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(The include layout visibility is set to "gone" so I think that shouldn't affect)

Code for bottom navigation view color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorNavigationIconSelected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/colorNavigationIconHold" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorNavigationIconNotSelected" />
</selector>
```

Code for style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorButton</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorHintText</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/jipatharegular</item>
</style>
```

Any way to make color of the icon accurate?

Comment: Post your layout/code/style

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I added the style and layout that contains the bottom navigation.

Comment: Is it possible to change `app:itemIconTint` instead of `android:color` inside `<selector>`? My initial guess is that the color is mixed with the tint, which is why it's different. But I haven't checked on it.

Comment: @Beko I tried but the selector still asked me to put `android:color`